# CKAN : ValueError: VDM only works with SQLAlchemy versions 0.4 through 0.9, not: 1.1.2

Tags: ckan, python

Do I need to upgrade the package vdm to make it compatible with sqlalchemy version greater then 0.9?

This is a CKAN question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36161190/2327328 and https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/requirements.txt

Comment: @philshem my concern is not about the working. But how to make it work through with other versions of sqlalchemy, I know about its compatible versions.would request you to please revert the question from "holding it off" :)

Comment: That’s then a programming question for stack overflow. Or GitHub issue at ckan’s repository.

Comment: I’ve re-opened but will close if other users flag it

Comment: In general, consider using a virtual environment when dealing with various versions of python and packages

Comment: @philshem, I have actually made the respective changes, but being a beginner, I do not know the changes required to be done while making a package upgrade compatible with already existing package.and bdw thanks for the info.